# Scala TabbedPane Custom Page Subclass

Tags: swing, scala, subclass, subclassing

I have a problem with my custom subclass of `Page`. Here is a short example.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val pane = new TabbedPane
  pane.pages += new LanguagePage("common_yes", new Label)
  println(pane.pages(0).isInstanceOf[LanguagePage])
}

class LanguagePage(languageKey: String, com: Component) 
  extends Page("", com, null) {

  def method() {...}
}
```

When I run the program, `false` is printed. It would be nice to know why this happens and how I can access my added page again. In my case I need to run the method that the subclass has to adjust the title string based on the language that is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source

```
class TabbedPane extends Component with Publisher {
  object pages extends BufferWrapper[Page] {
    def apply(n: Int) = 
      new Page(TabbedPane.this, peer.getTitleAt(n),
        UIElement.cachedWrapper[Component] 
        (peer.getComponentAt(n).asInstanceOf[javax.swing.JComponent]),
        peer.getToolTipTextAt(n))
```

you always get a new instance.

Looking at

```
class TabbedPane extends Component with Publisher {
  object pages extends BufferWrapper[Page] {

  def +=(t: Page): this.type = { 
    t.parent = TabbedPane.this
    peer.addTab(t.title, null, t.content.peer, t.tip)
    this
  }
```

the argument `t` is not recorded at all.

But you can change the title using

```
pane.pages(0).title = "Title 2"
```

so you could define a *logical* page (a companion in addition to the Swing page) separately. Using a reference to the pane and the tab index this class can change the title.

Comment: Thanks! I now map the tab index to all data needed to generate the title of the tab. Then i loop through the map and set the title of all tabs.